# How do i write media query for galaxy note 5

Tags: css, media-queries

I need media query code on both landscape and portrait mode for a Samsung galaxy note 5. I am using the following media query, but I think this is no right:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

Am I missing something, or is this correct?

Comment: not possible to write media query as per device but possible to write per resolution

Comment: Ok i am new to media queries what this the perfect code for screens a bit larger than phones like note devices in general or iphone 6 plus i mean that type of screens

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to be able to target devices specifically. That sounds like hell for us developers.

Comment: Use media queries to define breakpoints where it makes sense for your content to reflow, rather than trying to target specific devices. That way, when the next device comes out in a few months, your site will still look great.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to go after every device is a fool's errand. Not calling you a fool, it's a saying lol ;) Devices change frequently according to their latest OS update. instead, use resolution and leave enough margin of error to account for most devices. However, if you do decide to embark in this mission, use this:

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {}
```

As long as you are using your widths to be 100% and your body has a gutter of at least 15px, your widths will adapt accordingly.

My advice, use a responsive framework such as Bootstrap, specially Bootstrap4 which it caters to large mobile devices such as iPhone6 and Notes

Comment: I agree with your advice. Incidentally, the S5 and Note 5 are [not the same](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-5,Samsung-Galaxy-S5/phones/9462,8202).

Comment: Noted, I referred him to the link where I believe they list the Note 5. I'll fix the answer in case someone looks and doesn't bother to go check the link. Good catch! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good website if you want to try and target certain devices. I would post the information but the list and database is quite large. http://viewportsizes.com/

Comment: You could try to only show the rules for the requested size?

Answer (score -2):

```
@media only screen and(max-width:360px)
{ 
    //code here..    
}
```

Comment: No explanation, no details, wrongly formatted... Have a look around SO to see some good examples of answers, this is not it. Also, a Galaxy Note probably reports more than 360 pixels as width...